# How to initialize a pointer to a dynamic 2D Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, 2d

I was giving a adventurer class containing a bunch of functions and member variables. 
One of them is:

```
string*** items;
```

so first I thought it was a 3d array that I have to make but I was told that it suppose to be a pointer to a 2d array.

What I tried to do was make a temp array

```
string** temp;
```

Init that and fill it, I then point my items to temp

```
items = &temp;
```

This works till the function exits. Then we I try and call a index value inside items

```
cout<<*item[0][0];
```

there is nothing. When temp disappears so does the array.

This line also doenst work

```
(*items) = new string*[2];
```

I couldn't find anything online  that helped me.

How can I initialize items or keep the array data that i made using temp.

For those asking for the code, this is what they gave me:

```
class Adventurer{
private:
    string*** items;
    string name;
    double maxCarryWeight;
    double currentCarryWeight;
    int currentNumberOfItems;
    int maxNumberOfItems;
    double health;
    static int numberOfAdventurers;


public:
    Adventurer(); //default constructor
    Adventurer(const Adventurer& a);  //copy constructor
    ~Adventurer();
    bool pickUpItem(string it, double weight);
    bool dropItem(string it);
    bool dropItem(int index);
    void setName(string n);
    string getName() const;
    void setMaxCarryWeight(double w);
    double getMaxCarryWeight() const;
    void setCurrentCarryWeight(double w);
    double getCurrentCarryWeight() const;    
    void setMaxNumberOfItems(int n);
    int getMaxNumberOfItems() const;
    void setCurrentNumberOfItems(int n);
    int getCurrentNumberOfItems() const;
    int getNumberOfAdventurers() const;
    void setHealth(double h);
    double getHealth() const;
    string** getItem(int index) const;
    Adventurer& operator = (const Adventurer& a);
};
```

And said that

```
string*** items;
```

is a pointer to a 2d array

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" your next thought should be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I am not allowed to use a vector.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ   Ive been googling for 4 hours now and nothing ive found has help me.

Comment: @KeatonRoux Improve your google fu! Also if you _aren't allowed_ to use `std::vector` you're not actually learning c++.

Comment: They trying to get us familiar with pointers I guess. Making alot of usless functions and variables to teach us.

Comment: Instead of trying to describe your code in text, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Comment: Also, don't strive to become a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer). It's usually *not* a compliment.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have no choice. I have to use ***Items. Im not allowed to edit the header file

Comment: Find a better C++ teacher and not one who seems to believe that this language is "C with classes".

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury I wish I could but this is a Practical for one of my University classes. So i don't really have much of a choice. Got to do it for the marks

Comment: How do you allocate `temp`? Or better still, show us your code.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: in a learning situation, it can make sense to let people do things "on foot" and not let them use the more convenient features right away.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I can understand that logic but it doesn't make much sense in this case as trying to teach C++ whilst forbidding the use of the STL is like trying to learn English without knowing the alphabet.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: otherwise you get programmers who know how to use, say, a vector but don't know anything about the basics, like pointers.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: I think people should first learn simple English words and simple sentences before you let them write an essay about a more complicated subject, like e.g. the role of clergy in the history of Great Britain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve from your question but it seems your main issue is likely to do with returning the address of a local variable when attempting to allocate your 2D C-style `std::string` array. Below is a very basic example of how to avoid such an issue via returning the allocated 2D array and then taking the address of this returned value and storing it in your `std::string*** items` variable.

```
// allocate memory for a 2D C-style array of std::string's
std::string** allocate_2d_array(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) {
    std::string** items_arr = new std::string*[rows];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        items_arr[i] = new std::string[cols];
    return items_arr;
}
// print each element of the 2D C-style array via a pointer to the array
void print_items(std::ostream& os, std::string*** items, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            os << (*items)[i][j] << ' ';
        os << '\n';
    }
}
// destruct the 2D C-style array
void deallocate_2d_array(std::string** items_arr, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        delete[] items_arr[i];
    delete[] items_arr;
}
int main(void) {
    std::size_t rows = 3;  // matrix rows
    std::size_t cols = 3;  // matrix columns
    // allocate a 2D array of std::string's
    std::string** items_arr = allocate_2d_array(items, 3, 3);
    // set the pointer to a 2D std::string array to address of items_arr
    std::string*** items = &items_arr;
    int count = 0;
    // fill items_arr with data via items pointer
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) 
            (*items)[i][j] = std::to_string(++count);
    }
    print_items(std::cout, items); // print matrix to terminal
    deallocate_2d_array(items_arr, rows, cols);  // deallocate items_arr
}
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, this is not in keeping with modern c++ and one would much rather use a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` to store a matrix of `std::string` instances.

You mentioned that using `std::vector` is not an option but I suspect that your teacher probably didn't say anything about making your own barebones dynamic array with similar semantics to a `std::vector` so that is always one way around these silly restrictions. With that in mind, below is the framework for a very basic (and untested) class which mimics a `std::vector` (without using allocators) which would make your task much simpler.

```
template<typename Ty>
class dynamic_array {
public:
    typedef Ty value_type;
    typedef Ty& reference;
    typedef const Ty& const_reference;
    typedef Ty* pointer;
    typedef const Ty* const_pointer;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    // CONSTRUCTION/ASSIGNMENT
    dynamic_array()
        : arr_capacity(0), arr_size(0) {}
    dynamic_array(size_type count)
        : arr_capacity(count), arr_size(count) { allocate(count); }
    ~dynamic_array() { destroy(); }
    dynamic_array& operator=(dynamic_array _other) {
        swap(*this, _other);
        return *this;
    }
    // CAPACITY
    bool empty() const noexcept { return arr_size; }
    size_type size() const noexcept { return arr_size; }
    size_type capacity() const noexcept { return arr_capacity; }
    void reserve(size_type new_cap) { if (new_cap > arr_capacity) reallocate(new_cap); }
    // ELEMENT ACCESS
    reference operator[](size_type n) { return arr[n]; }
    const_reference operator[](size_type n) const { return arr[n]; }
    // MODIFIERS
    void clear() {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i)
            (&arr[i])->~value_type();
        arr_size = 0;
    }
    void push_back(const value_type& _val) {
        if (arr_size == arr_capacity) // TODO: expand arr using reallocate
        pointer val = new (arr + arr_size) value_type(_val);
        ++arr_size;
    }
    void pop_back() {
        (&arr[arr_size-1])->~value_type();
        --arr_size;
    }
    void swap(dynamic_array& _other) {
        std::swap(arr, _other.arr);
        std::swap(arr_capacity, _other.arr_capacity);
        std::swap(arr_size, _other.arr_size);
    }
    static void swap(dynamic_array& lhs, dynamic_array& rhs) { lhs.swap(rhs); }
private:
    value_type* arr;
    size_type arr_capacity;
    size_type arr_size;
    void allocate(size_type n) { arr = new value_type[n]; }
    void reallocate(size_type new_cap) {
        value_type* tmp = new value_type[new_cap];
        size_type tmp_rows = (new_cap > arr_capacity) ? arr_capacity : new_cap;
        for (size_type i = 0; i < tmp_rows; ++i)
            tmp[i] = std::move(arr[i]);
        delete[] arr;
        arr = tmp;
        arr_capacity = new_cap;
    }
    void destroy { clear(); delete[] arr; }
};
```

Then instead of messing around with lots of raw pointers and the headaches they bring, you can just pass around your `dynamic_array<dynamic_array<std::string>>` class instance without needing to worry about memory management.

---

*Note: The above `dynamic_array` class is untested and probably requires some tweaks, it is also not a great example of implementing a STL-style container (you'd need allocator and iterator support), it is just intended as a barebones `std::vector` mimicking container to get around the "no vector" task requirement.*